# How to resize image assets for all Apple devices? (not launch images)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, assets

My app displays 2 buttons on the top and a car picture (1 of 4 possible) at the bottom:

[image: app screenshot]

Each image file has huge dimensions of 5616 x 3744 pixels and the app lags noticeably and also sometimes crashes (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMFZA.jpg), **Aspect Fill** mode is used):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

So I would like to scale down the image assets and include these files (for each of the 4 car pictures) in my app:

- car.jpg
- car@2x.jpg
- car@3x.jpg

After searching around and I think I have to target the [Rendered Pixels](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2015/iphone-6-screen-size-web-design-tips/) sizes, that is:

- 640 x 960 for iPhone 4
- 640 x 1136 for iPhone 5
- 750 x 1334 for iPhone 6
- 1242 x 2208 for iPhone 6 Plus
- and I have yet to look up the dimensions of iPads

However my image view has 20 pixels insets (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHI2y.jpg)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

So I am not sure, which value to subtract from the widths of car.jpg, car@2x.jpg and car@3x.jpg.

Should I subtract 40 pixels from each file (that is 20 on the left and 20 on the right)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just resize the image to the largest it will be (@3x) - it will be significantly smaller than it is at the moment, `aspect fill` will take care of the rest

Comment: What **width** should my car@3x.jpg have? Should it be `1242 - 3 * (20 + 20)` pixels?